# How much disk space does Android OS 4.1.1 take?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

I recently received a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 with Android 4.1.1 on it. This is the 8GB model. I am curious to know, how much disk space does the Android OS take up? I did not think about 3.5GB was needed for the OS. Is this true? I ask only because my disk space available says I have 4.49GB left.

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between "how much the Android OS requires" and "how much the manufacturer reserved". Remember, the OS has its own partition (`/system`), which is mounted read-only during normal operation (just made writable for OS updates), while the user's data goes to `/data`. Moreover, most manufacturers add their own "presents" (also known as [bloatware](/questions/tagged/bloatware)) to the `/system` partition.

So while the actual Android system usually fits into less than 1 GB (considered there are devices shipping with less internal storage), your device's manufacturer might have decided to reserve more space for future updates and his own add-ons.

Comment: Just to clarify, examples of these add-ons are bundled software (facebook, customized calendar app etc.), customized user interface/launcher (TouchWiz) and the whole S Pen software.

Comment: how would I check how much the manufacturer reserved. I'm just trying to figure out why I only have 4.49GB of space left

Comment: Either use `adb shell` or a Terminal app (e.g. [Android Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm), and run `df`. The "reserved area" is mounted at `/system`. There are other partitions like e.g. `/cache` which are not directly accessible to you; "userland" is `/data`, where you should find your 4.49 GB.